# Username can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cloud9-ide

So I enter a username, email, and password (+password confirmation) and it once I hit submit, it says: "Username can't be blank" and I clearly entered a username.

Here is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 16

  }
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

This is my registrations_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

And the following is my new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :user_name %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

add_username_to_users.rb (migration)

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    add_index :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

If there's any other needed to be posted, to find more about the error, please comment. Also, note that I have devise gem (properly installed) and I'm using a cloud 9 editor. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have your code on github?

Comment: @jdgray https://ide.c9.io/kingsong/instagram

Comment: Can you show you migration file here?

Answer (score 5):

When reviewing your code on c9.io there is definitely an issue with your migrations file where you have this:

```
class CreateAddUserNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :add_user_name_to_users do |t|
      t.string :user_name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

That actually created a table called `add_user_name_to_users`, which you can find in your `schema.rb` file. So when you are creating your `User` with the sign up form, there is no `user_name` to validate on the `User`'s table since it does not exist. You should remove your migration file `20171231162016_create_add_user_name_to_users.rb` since it is not what you are looking to do or drop the table ([here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) are some docs for changing your migrations).

Instead make sure you follow this devise documentation on adding a `user_name` as a sign up/ sign in parameter [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

You also have a `models` table that has the same fields as your `users` table (also assuming that this was put here by accident. Make sure you double check your migrations as it looks like that was one of the results of the error you are seeing.

Comment: So I've deleted the `20171231162016_create_add_user_name_to_users.rb`. Now I should check the docs to change my migrations.

Comment: You can either do that or drop that table, then add `user_name` to your `users` table

Comment: I accidentally linked to the wrong cloud 9. The one I sent you belongs to my sister, we are working on the same thing. https://ide.c9.io/kingsong/instagram-rose That one is mine. I have followed the docs. I've generated the migration and migrated it.

Comment: And changed my application to: `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end`

Comment: You have two user names referenced (`user_name` and `username`), make sure you stay consistent

Comment: @iiRosie1 did my answer help you solve your question?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: My answer to your question (your question posted above my answer..). You originally had a bounty and asked if my answer helped with your question.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.